# How do I add a custom image in a block (unique for every page)?

Tags: blocks, media

I have a block at the top of my site used for an image slider on the home page (using Nivo Slider), and I need to allow the users to add a custom image to fill that block space for any pages created (aside from home page).  This image will be different per page.  How can I do this?

I'm running Drupal 6

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  See [this link](http://www.codigovision.com/drupal-6x-upload-image-page-and-display-block) for the answer.